# upgrading from hyperledger composer v0.16 to v0.20.2

Tags: node.js, authentication, acl, hyperledger-composer

I am upgrading my tutorial from composer v0.16 to composer v0.20.2 Most of the upgrade has gone smoothly, however I'm running into an authentication problem that I can't get around. I'm going through a step-wise process to create and activate a user. In v0.16, I did the following:

- ADD a new member to a registry
- ISSUE identity for the new member
- CREATE and IMPORT a card for the new member
- PING the business network using the new member ID

The last step 'activated' the member, so that they could do productive work in the network. In v0.20, the first 3 steps still work flawlessly, however the PING step now returns the following error:

```
transaction returned with failure: AccessException: 
Participant 'org.acme.Z2BTestNetwork.Buyer#rdd@xyz.com' does not have 'READ' access to resource
'org.hyperledger.composer.system.Network#zerotoblockchain-network@0.1.5'
```

I've simplified my permissions.acl file down to just the following 3 statements:

```
rule Z2BTestFullAccess {
    description: "Allow all participants access to all resources"
    participant: "org.acme.Z2BTestNetwork.Buyer"
    operation: READ
    resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
    action: ALLOW
}

rule NetworkAdminUser {
    description: "Grant business network administrators full access to user resources"
    participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
    operation: ALL
    resource: "**"
    action: ALLOW
}

rule NetworkAdminSystem {
    description: "Grant business network administrators full access to system resources"
    participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
    operation: ALL
    resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
    action: ALLOW
}
```

I can further simplify the first rule to be

```
rule Z2BTestFullAccess {
    description: "Allow all participants access to all resources"
    participant: "ANY"
    operation: ALL
    resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
    action: ALLOW
}
```

But it still fails with the same error message.

composer card list for the new card returns:

```
userName:            rdd-xyz.com
description:         
businessNetworkName: zerotoblockchain-network
identityId:          6c6eab0d11d26ccfc4a8164dbe971814d2120802e84d1b3b98b16ceb2cb80334
roles:               none
connectionProfile: 
  name:   hlfv1
  x-type: hlfv1
credentials:         Credentials set
```

composer network ping for the new card returns the same error as the nodejs code.

How do I determine the root cause of this error and, more importantly, how do I resolve this? Happy to add code segments for each step if that will help.

Comment: I would think you need to create a rule that grants access to your Business Network in addition to the System Namespaces.  So an Allow rule with resource: "org.acme.Z2BTestNetwork.*"

Comment: That would have been sweet if the fix was that easy. Unfortunately, adding that in yields the same response. Not terribly surprising, since the error message is able to identify the requesting user & role (org.acme.Z2BTestNetwork.Buyer#bd); the access issue is with the business network deployed into hl fabric by composer (org.hyperledger.composer.system.Network#zerotoblockchain-network@0.1.5). 

Thanks, anyway. It was worth a shot.

Comment: Could you post your complete ACL file that is failing ? If you give any participant full access to org.hyperledger.composer.system.** then that will give any participant read access to the business network and I gave this a quick go (copied directly from that acl example posted above) and it worked. So I wonder if there is a previous ACL rule in your file that is explicitly denying access ?

Comment: For this test, the acl shown above is the full permissions.acl file.